# Fill missing gaps in data using a date column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a temp table that returns this output

```
PRICE | DATE 
1.491500 |  2019-02-01 
1.494000 |  2019-02-04 
1.486500 |  2019-02-06
```

I want to fill in the missing gaps in data by duplicating the last known record prior to the gaps in data using the date.   Is their a way to update the existing temp table or create a new temp table with this desired output dynamically:

```
PRICE | DATE 
1.491500 |  2019-02-01 
1.491500 |  2019-02-02
1.491500 |  2019-02-03 
1.494000 |  2019-02-04 
1.494000 |  2019-02-05 
1.486500 |  2019-02-06
```

I am working on sql server 2008r2

Comment: Please add the tag of the SQL Server version you're using; the version could change the best answer.

Comment: sorry about that, I am working on sql server 2008r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because SQL Server does not support `IGNORE NULLS` in `LAG()` this is a bit tricky.  I would go for a recursive subquery of the form:

```
with cte as (
      select price, date, dateadd(day, -1, lead(date) over (order by date)) as last_date
      from t
      union all
      select price, dateadd(day, 1, date), last_date
      from cte
      where date < last_date
     )
select price, date
from cte
order by date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=28c125ca641ab53b6eff5e2df2d0db47) is a db<>fiddle.

In SQL Server 2008, you can replace the `lead()` with:

```
with cte as (
      select price, date, 
             (select min(date)
              from t t2
              where t2.date > t.date
             ) as last_date
      from t
      union all
      select price, dateadd(day, 1, date), last_date
      from cte
      where date < last_date
     )
select price, date
from cte
order by date;
```

Comment: I am working with sql server 2008r2, we don't have compatibility for lead function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a dates table (if not you can easily make one), you can do this by left joining the existing table to the dates table. Thereafter assign groups per dates found using a running sum. The max value per group is what would be needed to fill in the missing values.

```
select dt,max(price) over(partition by grp) as price
from (select p.price,d.dt,sum(case when p.dt is null then 0 else 1 end) over(order by d.dt) as grp
      from dates d 
      left join prices p on p.dt = d.dt
     ) t
```

**[`Sample Demo`](https://rextester.com/ZYEUN28079)**

Making a dates table with a recursive cte. Persist it as needed.

```
--Generate dates in 2019
with dates(dt) as (select cast('2019-01-01' as date)
                   union all
                   select dateadd(day,1,dt)
                   from dates
                   where dt < '2019-12-31'
                  )
select * from dates
option(maxrecursion 0)
```